# Docker: Different ENV variables for development and production environments

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, supervisord

I have Docker container, which I deploy on Amazon ECS. The Docker container runs supervisord, which in turn runs 3 different programs.

Naturally, I'd like to use different environment variables for local development vs production to differentiate API keys, API endpoints and so on. What's a good way of doing this?

Is this something I should setup in the Dockerfile, Amazon ECS or the supervisord conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. You can specify ENV variables when creating the task definition on Amazon ECS.

Answer (score 0):

If ECS allows you to specify `docker run` switches, then you could use `--env-file` and point to a different file for each environment i.e. prod.env, dev.env.

Comment: Thanks. That would probably be possible, but I found another solution that I posted here, which I think is simpler.

Comment: there's probably a cooling off period, but don't forget to accept your own answer to help search results.